# Difference in minutes between two hours

Tags: javascript

### The goal

Get the minutes' difference between two hours, like: `12:20:00` and `12:15:00`. The result is: `5`.

### The problem

I have a string in PHP that "houses" some time, like the example above. And with JavaScript, I need to **enable a button** when the minutes' difference is greater than 3. In other words, this is what I have in PHP: `10:00:00` and this is what the `Date()` object brings to me in JavaScript: `Thu Oct 10 2013 11:29:49 GMT-0300 (Hora oficial do Brasil)`.

I need to get the `11:29:49` and compare with `10:00:00` to get the minutes' difference. If this difference is greater than 3, then *do something*.

### Code spotlight

This is what I'm trying, but *doesn't work*, of course. It's impossible to calculate the difference because the variable's type are different.

```
<script>
var date = new Date();
    nowInHours = date.getHours() + ":" 
                 + date.getMinutes() + ":" 
                 + date.getSeconds(),
    fantasyHours = <?php $application->time(); ?>;

console.log(fantasyHours - nowInHours);
</script>
```

**Can someone give me an idea?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, manage your time like a boss. Times in programming language are calculated as the number of second or millisecond since a setted date (what we call a Unix timestamp - *1 January 1970 00:00:00 UTC*).

As you'll understand, having a date in this standard format is the best as you simply have two integer you can compare.

In JavaScript and PHP, these date format are the default and very easy to use.

JS: `new Date().getTime()`
PHP: `time()` and the date constructor (But here I can't help much, the business logic of your application is only known by you)

So, convert your time from PHP in a convenient standard format (the UTC format). Then use it to share dates between languages and compare them together.

Answer (score 0):

Convert both dates to miliseconds, and compare those.  If they are within 18000, they they are within 3 minutes.  Date.getTime() in js will do this for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can attempt to convert your PHP date to a Javascript date before working on it with the help of some Regex or String.split function.

See [Javascript Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

Answer (score 0):

Can you not use JodaTime, convert both you dates to LocalDateTime then compare? This appears to work:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    LocalDateTime date1 = new LocalDateTime(2013,10,10,12,15,0);
    LocalDateTime date2 = new LocalDateTime(2013,10,10,12,20,0);

    assertEquals( 5, Minutes.minutesBetween(date1, date2).getMinutes() );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`var fantasyHours = new Date(<?php echo $application->time(); ?> * 1000)`

That should give you the time from PHP to JavaScript. You can now check both date objects to see the diffrence.

The *1000 is needed because the PHP unix time is in seconds and `new Date()` needs miliseconds.